# Attenuator impedance is not the expected value at higher frequency

Tags: attenuator, high-impedance

I have recently made a High Z (1 MΩ) attenuator with R1= R3= 8.75 MΩ, and R2= 243 kΩ. I am using an LCR meter to test the impedance at higher frequencies. At frequencies above 50 kHz, the impedance is much smaller than the 1 MΩ intended value. I am using the mean sum method where   `Z= sqrt ((R of closed circuit) * (R of open circuit))`

Keep in mind, the method I am using for calculating impedance is just a method of estimation. Moreover, I am an amateur; so please keep in mind obvious mistakes are not so obvious for me.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdfGpR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Show us your PCB layout.

Comment: The point is, at high frequencies and high resistances, even tiny parasitic capacitances become very significant. For example, at 50 kHz, just 3 pF of stray capacitance has an impedance of 1 megohm, which is low enough to affect your measurements.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @DaveTweed, capacitors have some impedance ...

One can note the "evolution" of global impedance of attenuator.

[image]